# Can outclass specify inner class with InnerClassNameOuter directly rather than ClassName.InnerClassName

Tags: java

In Inner classes of Thinking In Java,

> If you want to make an object of the inner class anywhere except from
>   within a non-static method of the outer class, you must specify the
>   type of that object as OuterClassName.InnerClassName, as seen in
>   main().

But I find use InnerClassName directly still works in main.

```
   public class Parcel2 {
        class Contents {
            private int i = 42;
            public int value() { return i; }
        }
        class Destination {
            private String label;
            Destination(String whereTo){
                label = whereTo;
            }
            String readLabel(){ return label; }
        }

        public Destination to(String s){
            return new Destination(s);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Parcel2 q = new Parcel2();  

            /* Destionation d = q.to("Borneo");      still works.*/ 
            Parcel2.Destination d = q.to("Borneo"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a matter of scope. The name `Destination` is in scope within the entire body of the class that declares it.

Comment: Your text is unclear. "To make an object" means to create a new instance using the `new` operator, and you do not do that using `OuterClassName.InnerClassName`. A qualified name like that can be use to *declare a variable* of the specified type, and you don't need to qualify it like that, even from other classes, as long as you `import` the inner class name. Simply declaring a variable of the inner class doesn't make the object. It just makes a reference variable.